# Same keymaps in IntelliJ IDEA and Atom editor

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, webstorm, atom-editor, keymapping

I use WebStorm, Android Studio and Atom.

Android Studio and WebStorm I just export settings but atom I cant import settings from IntellJ IDEA.

How can I keep the same shortcuts (keymaps) from IntelliJ and Atom editor?

There are any tool that I can export keymaps from IntelliJ into Atom format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched everywhere for this when i started atom. Sadly i never found anything. This is by no means a complete map. Just some of the ones i used the most. The keymap system in atom was very frustrating and took a while for some things.
But here you go if any will be of help to you.
Also, here is my `.atom` folder.

https://github.com/j-walker23/dotfiles/tree/develop/atom/atom.symlink

```
'body':
  'cmd-h': 'unset!'

'html atom-text-editor.vim-mode.normal-mode':
  'U': 'core:redo'
  'cmd-1': 'tree-view:toggle-focus'
  'L': 'vim-mode:move-to-last-character-of-line'
  'cmd-F': 'formatter:format-code'
  'cmd-shift-c': 'window:toggle-dev-tools'
  'cmd-.': 'key-peek:toggle'
  'cmd->': 'key-binding-resolver:toggle'

  'cmd-k h':  'pane:split-left-creating-empty-pane'
  'cmd-k l': 'pane:split-right-creating-empty-pane'
  'cmd-k k':    'pane:split-up-creating-empty-pane'
  'cmd-k j':  'pane:split-down-creating-empty-pane'

  'cmd-k m h':  'pane:split-left-moving-current-tab'
  'cmd-k m l': 'pane:split-right-moving-current-tab'
  'cmd-k m k':    'pane:split-up-moving-current-tab'
  'cmd-k m j':  'pane:split-down-moving-current-tab'

  'cmd-I': 'pane-move:down'
  'cmd-H': 'pane-move:left'
  'cmd-L': 'pane-move:right'
  'cmd-K': 'pane-move:up'


'html .platform-darwin atom-text-editor.vim-mode:not(.insert-mode)':
  'cmd-p': 'clipboard-plus:toggle'
  'cmd-shift-v': 'clipboard-plus:toggle'


'atom-text-editor.vim-mode.normal-mode':
  'o': 'custom:newline-below'
  'O': 'custom:newline-above'

'atom-panel.clipboard-plus, atom-panel .project-manager, .platform-darwin .command-palette, .fuzzy-finder':
  'J': 'core:move-down'
  'K': 'core:move-up'

'atom-text-editor:not(.mini).vim-mode:not(.insert-mode):not(.jumpy-jump-mode)':
    'f':    'jumpy:toggle'

'html atom-workspace':
  'cmd-n': 'tree-view:add-file'
  'cmd-shift-o': 'fuzzy-finder:toggle-file-finder'

'html .platform-darwin atom-text-editor':
  # 'cmd-e': 'recent-files-fuzzy-finders:toggle-finder'
  'cmd-b': 'symbols-view:go-to-declaration'
  'cmd-shift-b': 'symbols-view:return-from-declaration'
  'cmd-r': 'find-and-replace:show-replace'
  'cmd-[': 'last-cursor-position:previous'
  'cmd-]': 'last-cursor-position:next'

'html .platform-darwin atom-text-editor.vim-mode:not(.insert-mode)':
  'n': 'find-and-replace:find-next'

'atom-workspace atom-pane, atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not(.mini)':
  'cmd-k n l': 'window:focus-pane-on-right'
  'cmd-k n h': 'window:focus-pane-on-left'
  'cmd-k n j': 'window:focus-pane-below'
  'cmd-k n k': 'window:focus-pane-above'
```